# Jmeter -How to call different csv file in a single thread group?

Tags: csv, jmeter

We are using a gps tracking application.In each 4 second the device longitude and latitudes will change.For load testing we used jmeter and the parameter are passed through  csv file.CSV file have field like tripid,deviceid, latitude,longitude... so need to change the  latitude,longitude values in each 4 seconds.

So we are keeping data in different csv files.But i dont know how to call csv file one by one in a single thread group.Under the Thread group used TCP sample.

Answer (score 0):

Add multiple CSV Data config sets to single thread group and configure them for different csv files used by your application/load testing.

In your script you can use values from different csv config sets (with different names of course) without any issue.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you keep all the data in the single CSV file? Variable names can be comma-separated and you can read lon, lat, tripid and deviceid from the same file. See [Using CSV Data Set Config](http://community.blazemeter.com/knowledgebase/articles/65138-using-csv-data-set-config) guide for example.

Feel free to ask in comments section if you're still uncertain.